# Facebook PHP SDK auth between main domain and multiple subdomains

Tags: authentication, facebook-php-sdk

I really don't manage to make this work. I've tried already all the steps I've found on SO or other websites, but my cross-domain fb authentication doesn't work..

How my auth script looks like:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0,"/",".my-domain.com");
session_start();

// include facebook class
try {
  $fb = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $facebook_app_id,
    'secret' => $facebook_app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
  ));
} catch(FacebookAPIException $e) {
  // no active fb session
}

// other content here

try {
  $uid = $fb->getUser();

  if($uid) {
    $user = $fb->api('/me','GET');  
  }

} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
  // not logged in
}
```

Now the problem is that this code works perfect on `my-domain.com` but not on `subdomain.my-domain.com`.

Even if I successfully authenticate on the main domain `my-domain.com`, when I'm visiting `subdomain.my-domain.com` the session of the main domain is replaced and the connection is lost.

**Note** that in the case of `subdomain.my-domain.com` there is no API Exception thrown but the `$uid` is 0.

I've already set the domain on FB APP Settings page as `my-domain.com`.

Which is the problem here?

Comment: Check the cookie your browser receives – is it set with the settings you try to change dynamically?

Comment: I've already checked it and its domain is .my-domian.com with / path

Comment: Do you maybe have an “old” cookie set under your subdomain? What cookie value gets send back by the browser?

Comment: I've just removed all cookies and there is the same behaviour